# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small in Oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, date, difference

I want to calculate the time difference between two dates in Oracle sql query. I have written the following query:

```
DECLARE
 v_time varchar2(40); 
 diff_hours varchar2(40); 
 BEGIN
 select substr(((select date_time from observation_measurement where observation_measurement_id=2861971)), 1,17)
 into v_time
 from dual;

 dbms_output.put_line(v_time);

 select 24 * (to_date('06-25-2014 09:46:36', 'MM-DD-YYYY hh24:mi:ss') 
             - to_date(v_time, 'YY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')) into diff_hours 
       from dual;
END;
```

The first select statement returns correct result. When I am trying to calculate the time difference from current date to the previous calculated date then it is showing error. How can I get the correct result?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: have you tried after increasing the size of diff_hours variable?

Comment: Awesome. Increasing the size of diff_hours working. I didn't notice that. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing the size of diff_hours variable working. Thanks Krishna. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Make `diff_hours` a `NUMBER`variable instead of a `VARCHAR2` variable!

Of course you can make `diff_hours` long enough to hold all the insignificant decimals your query produces, but declaring it `VARCHAR2` is pointless anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have made some corrections in your query . Tell me if that works

```
DECLARE
 v_time varchar2(40);
-- Increase the size  
 diff_hours varchar2(200); 
 BEGIN
 select substr(((select date_time from observation_measurement where observation_measurement_id=2861971)), 1,17)
 into v_time
 from dual;

 dbms_output.put_line(v_time);
-- using the same format mask for both the dates
 select 24 * (to_date('06-25-2014 09:46:36', 'MM-DD-YYYY hh24:mi:ss') 
             - to_date(v_time, 'MM-DD-YYYY hh24:mi:ss')) into diff_hours 
       from dual;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increase diff_hours and it might work in some cases, but the problem is it might not work in other cases.

To be sure, you need explisitly convert number to string (example with 2 digits after dot):

```
select trunc(24*...., 2) into diff_hours
```